# Navigation with Grappelii on admin side in Django

Tags: django, django-admin, django-grappelli

I installed grappelli.dashboard. Follow all the steps, but still the navigation is not display.After installing dashboard dashboard.py file will be created. 
In that dashboard.py file "Group: Administration & Applications" ," Support" , "Latest Django News" , "Recent Actions" will be present.

Can anybody please tell me how to add the naviagtion?

I also want to add bookmarks functionality on admin side with grappelli in Django.
I am using Grappeli 2.3.8 with Django 1.4. Grappeli 2.0 having the functionality like bookmarks, navigation, but the New Grappeli version does having that. There will any way to customize it to add bookmarks?

Here is the code for dashboard.py

```
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

from grappelli.dashboard import modules, Dashboard
from grappelli.dashboard.utils import get_admin_site_name


class CustomIndexDashboard(Dashboard):
"""
Custom index dashboard for www.
"""

def init_with_context(self, context):
    site_name = get_admin_site_name(context)

    # append a group for "Administration" & "Applications"
    self.children.append(modules.Group(
        _('Group: Administration & Applications'),
        column=1,
        collapsible=True,
        children = [
            modules.AppList(
                _('Administration'),
                column=1,
                collapsible=False,
                models=('django.contrib.*',),
            ),
            modules.AppList(
                _('Applications'),
                column=1,
                css_classes=('collapse closed',),
                exclude=('django.contrib.*',),
            )
        ]
    ))

    # append an app list module for "Applications"
    self.children.append(modules.AppList(
        _('AppList: Applications'),
        collapsible=True,
        column=1,
        css_classes=('collapse closed',),
        exclude=('django.contrib.*',),
    ))

    # append an app list module for "Administration"
    self.children.append(modules.ModelList(
        _('ModelList: Administration'),
        column=1,
        collapsible=False,
        models=('django.contrib.*',),
    ))

    # append another link list module for "support".
    self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
        _('Media Management'),
        column=2,
        children=[
            {
                'title': _('FileBrowser'),
                'url': '/admin/filebrowser/browse/',
                'external': False,
            },
        ]
    ))

    # append another link list module for "support".
    self.children.append(modules.LinkList(
        _('Support'),
        column=2,
        children=[
            {
                'title': _('Django Documentation'),
                'url': 'http://docs.djangoproject.com/',
                'external': True,
            },
            {
                'title': _('Grappelli Documentation'),
                'url': 'http://packages.python.org/django-grappelli/',
                'external': True,
            },
            {
                'title': _('Grappelli Google-Code'),
                'url': 'http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/',
                'external': True,
            },
        ]
    ))

    # append a feed module
    self.children.append(modules.Feed(
        _('Latest Django News'),
        column=2,
        feed_url='http://www.djangoproject.com/rss/weblog/',
        limit=5
    ))

    # append a recent actions module
    self.children.append(modules.RecentActions(
        _('Recent Actions'),
        limit=5,
        collapsible=False,
        column=3,
    ))
```

Comment: please ask 1 question - I suggest removing the question about bookmarks and asking it later once you actually get bookmarks working. Can you post your dashboard.py? Is grappelli working?

Comment: Yes grappelli working properly. And dashboard is also set properly. "Support, "latest news" also display properly on admin side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved this issue. Customized the grappelli as like the old grappelli 2.0. Add the navigation classes into models.py and also add navigation block into the index.html file and it working. Change the style as like new Grappelli structure.